# Remove mention codes from message strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Currently i'm using *discord.js* and *markov* to make a bot who trains in my messages and then when mentioned replies using my trained data. The problem is, i'm seeding the markov chain with the messages, but when the messages have mentions embed the bot quickly become crazy and dives into a mention bomb.

The basic format of any mention is: all begin with `<@`, followed or not by `!`, then followed by a 18-digit unique id, and end with `>`. So `<@!372507467289985025>` and `<@372507467289985025>` are valid mentions produced by *discord.js*.

My question is *how* can i remove such mentions from the message string in node? I know it need to be made with wildcards/regex, but i cant find the right pattern which matches all variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but if you do:

```
let mention = /<@(.*?)>/;
```

This will match everything including, inbetween <@ and >. You can test regex expressions on https://regexr.com/ for matches

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how can you remove a property from elements in an array. This can easily be done with a `.map` call to iterate over the array and construct a new one:

```
const messagesWithoutMentions = message.content.map((message) => {
  const { mentions, ...rest } = message; // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Rest_syntax_parameters
  return { ...rest };
});
```

Comment: In fact what i think i need is to replace/remove part of the string. The mention format is something like `<@&714997550785663048>`, but i dont know how can i use regex or similar to remove parts with common patterns.

Comment: If you could show the full data structure of `message.content` that would be helpful

Comment: Its a string containing the message, and can have or not mentions in this format: `<@&123456789012345678>` eg. an 18-digit ID encased in `<@&>`